# Laravel mail layout issue when adding attachement

Tags: laravel, email, gmail, laravel-mail, laravel-notification

Having a problem with mail layout when adding an attachment
The layout goes to the right and keep empty space in the left side 
It happens just when i add an attachment and have this problem in gmail application
[show image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TKhav.png)

Comment: Looks like this is not a problem with your template, but the way the gmail app shows attachments

Comment: We need to see your source code. See [ask].